# End to end k-means clustering - python

Tags: clustering, k-means, python-3.x

i'd like to share with you my path in a **clustering exercise (via K-means using python)**, in order to understand if i made some errors or if there is something  more that can i do.

### General Overview

My dataset is composed by a customer base and their digital/non digital interactions (web visits, opened/clicked mail, number of live visits and so on). my goal is to find a way of cluster them in order to understand if there is a cluster let's say more digital (that interact more with digital world like mail, web ecc..)

### 1) First step

I Applied **Elbow method** and i getting the optimal number of cluster (i think between 2 and 3) this is the code and the result:

#### Inertia, or within-cluster sum-of-squares criterion:

`x = df[columns_2]
y = df
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 10), wcss)
plt.title('Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
plot.get_figure().savefig( "Elbow Method.png")`

[image]

### 2) Second step

I scaled my 13 metrics (all columns are numeric but not continuos, also they have a different range) and the i ran the **k-means**, here's the code:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x)
std_x = scaler.transform(x)
```

After a indication of my professor, i fixed `n_cluster = 3` instead of 2 and ran the k-means algorithm

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3 ,  init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(std_x)
```

### 3) Third step

After loooking at a summary clustered data i saw some resonable results (like in 2 of 3 cluster there's seems to be a good attitude with digital interactions, the first cluster is more close to website engagements while the second is more close to the email engagements. The third cluster shows a low engagement level with all digital channels) i decide to run the `silouhette score` in order to understand how good is this cluster, here's the code:

```
silouhette = metrics.silhouette_score(data, labels, metric='euclidean')
```

As you can see i decided to calculate it in all my dataset (so i didn't specified any `sample_size` parameter) and the result semms to be quite good `0.64`

#### My questions:

#### 1 Do you see any error in what i did? (i mean method and code errors)

#### 2 What do you think about the final result i'm getting?

#### 3 Is there something more that i can do? (in order to check if i'm doing thing in the right way)

Thank you